# Sync data between 2 databases Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, plsql, data-synchronization

I have 2 databases `DB_LIVE` and `DB_NEW`, both have different credentials. I have a Data Read access on `DB_LIVE` and I am owner of `DB_NEW` which is a completely blank and raw db provided to me.

I want to copy a table from `DB_LIVE` to `DB_NEW` and later keep syncing them. Another caveat is I only have PL/SQL developer and no SQL*Plus. Can someone please provide me pointers to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- on the destination database check that the origin database is listed in the tnsnames.ora
- Create a database link on the destination database to the origin database with a user on the origin database who has been granted select on the origin table.
- create a materialized view on the destination database which is filled with the statement `select * from origin_table@origin_database`
- schedule a refresh of the materialized view according to your needs. Note that you cannot do a fast refresh of only the changed values over a database link so this solution may not scale to millions of records

Answer (score 0):

On the machine where you installed your database you should have SQL*Plus installed.

For your question. Create a database link from `DB_NEW` to `DB_LIVE` and use your Read Data user. Now you can query the data.